# Requestmap not working in grails as expected

Tags: grails, groovy

In `Bootstrap.groovy` , I created a new requestmap with `ROLE_ADMIN` as configAttribute and /** as URL. When I logged in as `ROLE_ADMIN` ,I was able to access all URLs.

When I add a new requetsmap in UI with ROLE_TEST as configAttribute and /customer/** as URL, the user with ROLE_ADMIN cannot access the customer page. Even though ROLE_ADMIN has /** privilege.

Now, only users with `ROLE_TEST` can access customer page and not other users. 
What is desired of this feature is , Test user should be able to access only customer page and not any other page. However, currently Customer page can be accessed only by Test user.

```
Config.groovy
```

settings-

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.bi.report.auth.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.bi.report.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.bi.report.auth.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.bi.report.auth.Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
```

Bootstrap.groovy code

```
def loadRequestMap(){
        if (Requestmap.count()<=0) {
            new Requestmap(url: '/**', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()
            /*new Requestmap(url: '/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()*/
            new Requestmap(url: '/*/', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save();
            new Requestmap(url: '/logout/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY').save();
            new Requestmap(url: '/login/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
            new Requestmap(url: '/index/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.
Thank you.

Grails version `2.3.4`
Spring security plugin : `compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"`

Comment: @burtbeckwith have you come across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define **all** Roles which may access the URL.

For example:

`new Requestmap(url: '/admin/user/**', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR').save()`

☝️ says that users with either ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_SUPERVISOR may access the URL `/admin/user/**`

You may read more about it at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/requestMappings.html#requestmapInstances

`/**` for `ROLE_ADMIN` is not working the way you expect it to because the plugin calculates the most specific rule that applies to the current request.

`/customer/**` is more specific than `/**` so the associated role of `ROLE_TEST` is applied.

Comment: I am trying to make this dynamic. An admin user should be able to modify access permissions from UI without needing a restart. If I add two separate requestmaps for customer page, one for admin and another for test user, will that work?